# How to fix 413 payload too large

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, upload, size, payload

I have an application with frontend in Angular and backend in Net Core 5 that I'm testing locally. When I try to upload files that exceed a certain size the backend is never reached and the above error is returned to the frontend.

I run the frontend with ng serve. In my startup.cs, on backend, i added this code but it still doesn't work:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
   options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
});
```

Comment: are you using kestrel or IIS?

Comment: the backend is started with IIS

Comment: Could you kindly check the answer below? If it is not helpful, please let me know, tks~

Answer (score 0):

The settings of `options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;` or `options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;` are in the application level.

If you are using IIS or IIS Express(VS2022), we need to add below settings in  `web.config` file. **This settings is for machine level.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- 1 GB -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[I have verified the issue in this thread, you can check it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1356610/how-to-use-dash-or-hls-to-play-video-in-asp-net-co)